# how to detect a list of lists in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, nested-lists

```
lol([]).
lol([H|T]) :- lol(T).
lol([H|T]) :- lol(H).
```

I tried using this, but it returns true even for a normal 1d list.
how to get exactly true for 2d list? Or list in a list.

Comment: This is not an answer but should give you more food for thought. [Is there a has_type/2 for difference list?](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/is-there-a-has-type-2-for-difference-list/2622)

Comment: Have you considered starting off by doing examples by hand and then writing the code? As I often say, if you don't understand the problem and the code to solve it then why are your fingers on the keyboard.

Comment: yes, i did it for 5 hours, can you guide me a little ? Maybe i'm in a wrong way or so?

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

*A list has the "list of list" quality if and only if all of its elements are lists.*

Or in code, where we relax the "if and only if" equivalence to "if", which is good enough for our purposes:

```
% A vacuous truth:
% The empty list can be considered a list-of-lists as it contains 
% nothing at all

list_of_lists([]).              

% A list with at head element E is a list-of-lists if E is a list
% and and the Rest of the list is a list-of-lists.

list_of_lists([E|Rest]) :- actually_a_list(E), list_of_lists(Rest).
```

What's this `actually_a_list(E)`? It's where we test whether `E` is actually a list.

```
% The empty list is actually a list

actually_a_list([]).              

% A list with at head element we don't care about and name `_`
% is actually a list if the Rest of the list is actually a list

actually_a_list([_|Rest]) :- actually_a_list(Rest).
```

And so:

```
?- list_of_lists([]).             % certainly a list-of-lists
true.

?- list_of_lists(foo).            % clearly not a list, and not a list-of-lists
false.

?- list_of_lists([a,b,c]).        % a list but not a list-of-lists 
false.

?- list_of_lists([[a],[b,c]]).    % here is one!
true.

?- list_of_lists([[a],x,[b,c]]).  % nope
false.

?- list_of_lists([a,b|c]).        % this is not even a list
false.
```

In case we give the predicate an "open list" which has an unbound ending, in generates trivial endings containing only open lists:

```
?- list_of_lists([[a,b],[c,d]|Fin]).
Fin = [] ;
Fin = [[]] ;
Fin = [[], []] ;
Fin = [[], [], []] 
...
```

or perhaps clearer:

```
?- L=[[a,b],[c,d]|_],list_of_lists(L).
L = [[a, b], [c, d]] ;
L = [[a, b], [c, d], []] ;
L = [[a, b], [c, d], [], []] ;
L = [[a, b], [c, d], [], [], []] ;
L = [[a, b], [c, d], [], [], [], []] ;
L = [[a, b], [c, d], [], [], [], [], []] 
...
```

Comment: or just `maplist(is_list, L)`?

Comment: @ErikKaplun Yes but that takes all the fun out of the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

1- `lil predicate` will check how many inner lists we have. If greater than 0 than return true, else false.

2- `is_list` built-in will check each H if it is a list.

3- `Count` will count each time `is_list` finds a list.

4- `sum predicate` simply sums the count list, i.e. [1,1,1] = 3.

```
lil([H|T]):-
    Count=1,
    lil1([H|T],Count,TotalCount),
    sum(TotalCount,Sum),
    Sum>0.

lil1([],_,[]).
lil1([H|T],Count,[Count|List]):-
   is_list(H),
    Count1 is Count+0,
    lil1(T,Count1,List).

sum([],0).
sum([H|T],S):-
    sum(T,S1),
    S is S1+H.
```

**Example:**

```
?- lil([]).
false

?- lil([[w],[v,v,v]]).
true

?- lil([a,n,b,b]).
false

?- lil([[w],[v,v,v],s]).
false

?- lil([[w],[v,v,v],[s,s,s,s]]).
true

?- lil([[w]]).
true
```

Comment: it is usually a safer bet to take the empty list to be included in the type ‘list of X`...

Comment: This solution seems . . . way more complex than needs be.